# Track app (iOS/android) logs remotely

Tags: android, ios, logging, appcelerator

I'm developing android and iOS apps using Appcelerator Studio, there is any free way to check the logs (info, debug, log, warn & error) remotely?

I'd one client that singed up to an website, registered the app there, and was able to view all the logs from all the devices, but I don't know the name of it or if it's free.

Comment: I think you need some special library, because the default logs for Android & iOS are stripped & removed for release builds.

Comment: really? I thought that was necessary to remove all the logs before build the app, anyway, thanks for your comment, I'll keep searching

Comment: Yes. For Android, if  ```debuggable=false``` is added to any build types, all the logs will be stripped (not printed to the console). For iOs, is the same (there's no flag though). But always it's a good practice to remove the logs to prevent leaking infos if the app is reverse engineered. On Android you can remove them with proguard, on iOs...I suppose...search & delete :)).

Comment: I am using CocoaLumberjack for iOS and slf4j for Android. These frameworks write the logs to a file. I can send that file to a server. Do you want realtime logs?

Comment: I want the realtime logs, specially the ones that causes the app to crash, not only the ones that I write manually

Comment: Did you try to integrate Crashlytics? Try to read this https://github.com/shopmium/CrashlyticsModule/blob/master/documentation/index.md and this https://archive.appcelerator.com/question/181378/crashlytics-for-android-in-titanium

Comment: Requests for tools or services are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried Google Analytics? It's a great way of tracking both user behavior, events, errors and crashes, and it's free.

This [Ti.GA](https://github.com/benbahrenburg/Ti.GA) module for Titanium easy to use and definitely worth a try.